# Remove passed dates in CodeIgniter Calendar

Tags: php, codeigniter

Is it possible to remove the dates that have already passed (in the past) in [Codeigniter Calendar](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/calendar.html)?

I'm using the Calendar Template that was provided in the user's [manual](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/calendar.html)

Comment: So where do you wanna start the dates?

Comment: I don't think past days can be removed from calendar. It should be possible to change colors to gray so they look inactive.

Comment: How we can change colours to grey for all passed dates?

Answer (score 2):

This is possible although I don't know if it is conventional here is my code.

Save to "/application/libraries/MY_Calendar.php"

```
<?php

class MY_Calendar extends CI_Calendar {
    /**
     * Generate the calendar
     *
     * @param    int    the year
     * @param    int    the month
     * @param    array    the data to be shown in the calendar cells
     * @return    string
     */
    public function generate($year = '', $month = '', $data = array()) {
        $local_time = time();

        // Set and validate the supplied month/year
        if (empty($year)) {
            $year = date('Y', $local_time);
        } elseif (strlen($year) === 1) {
            $year = '200' . $year;
        } elseif (strlen($year) === 2) {
            $year = '20' . $year;
        }

        if (empty($month)) {
            $month = date('m', $local_time);
        } elseif (strlen($month) === 1) {
            $month = '0' . $month;
        }

        $adjusted_date = $this->adjust_date($month, $year);

        $month = $adjusted_date['month'];
        $year  = $adjusted_date['year'];

        // Determine the total days in the month
        $total_days = $this->get_total_days($month, $year);

        // Set the starting day of the week
        $start_days = array('sunday' => 0, 'monday' => 1, 'tuesday' => 2, 'wednesday' => 3, 'thursday' => 4, 'friday' => 5, 'saturday' => 6);
        $start_day  = isset($start_days[$this->start_day]) ? $start_days[$this->start_day] : 0;

        // Set the starting day number
        $local_date = mktime(12, 0, 0, $month, 1, $year);
        $date       = getdate($local_date);
        $day        = $start_day + 1 - $date['wday'];

        while ($day > 1) {
            $day -= 7;
        }

        // Set the current month/year/day
        // We use this to determine the "today" date
        $cur_year  = date('Y', $local_time);
        $cur_month = date('m', $local_time);
        $cur_day   = date('j', $local_time);

        $is_current_month = ($cur_year == $year && $cur_month == $month);

        // Generate the template data array
        $this->parse_template();

        // Begin building the calendar output
        $out = $this->replacements['table_open'] . "\n\n" . $this->replacements['heading_row_start'] . "\n";

        // "previous" month link
        if ($this->show_next_prev === TRUE) {
            // Add a trailing slash to the URL if needed
            $this->next_prev_url = preg_replace('/(.+?)\/*$/', '\\1/', $this->next_prev_url);

            $adjusted_date = $this->adjust_date($month - 1, $year);
            $out .= str_replace('{previous_url}', $this->next_prev_url . $adjusted_date['year'] . '/' . $adjusted_date['month'], $this->replacements['heading_previous_cell']) . "\n";
        }

        // Heading containing the month/year
        $colspan = ($this->show_next_prev === TRUE) ? 5 : 7;

        $this->replacements['heading_title_cell'] = str_replace('{colspan}', $colspan,
            str_replace('{heading}', $this->get_month_name($month) . '&nbsp;' . $year, $this->replacements['heading_title_cell']));

        $out .= $this->replacements['heading_title_cell'] . "\n";

        // "next" month link
        if ($this->show_next_prev === TRUE) {
            $adjusted_date = $this->adjust_date($month + 1, $year);
            $out .= str_replace('{next_url}', $this->next_prev_url . $adjusted_date['year'] . '/' . $adjusted_date['month'], $this->replacements['heading_next_cell']);
        }

        $out .= "\n" . $this->replacements['heading_row_end'] . "\n\n"
                            // Write the cells containing the days of the week
         . $this->replacements['week_row_start'] . "\n";

        $day_names = $this->get_day_names();

        for ($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++) {
            $out .= str_replace('{week_day}', $day_names[($start_day + $i) % 7], $this->replacements['week_day_cell']);
        }

        $out .= "\n" . $this->replacements['week_row_end'] . "\n";

        // Build the main body of the calendar
        while ($day <= $total_days) {
            $out .= "\n" . $this->replacements['cal_row_start'] . "\n";

            for ($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++) {
                if ($day > 0 && $day <= $total_days) {
                    $out .= ($is_current_month === TRUE && $day == $cur_day) ? $this->replacements['cal_cell_start_today'] : $this->replacements['cal_cell_start'];

                    if ($day < date('d')) {
                        $out .= '&nbsp;';
                    } elseif (isset($data[$day])) {
                        // Cells with content
                        $temp = ($is_current_month === TRUE && $day == $cur_day) ?
                        $this->replacements['cal_cell_content_today'] : $this->replacements['cal_cell_content'];
                        $out .= str_replace(array('{content}', '{day}'), array($data[$day], $day), $temp);
                    } else {
                        // Cells with no content
                        $temp = ($is_current_month === TRUE && $day == $cur_day) ?
                        $this->replacements['cal_cell_no_content_today'] : $this->replacements['cal_cell_no_content'];
                        $out .= str_replace('{day}', $day, $temp);
                    }

                    $out .= ($is_current_month === TRUE && $day == $cur_day) ? $this->replacements['cal_cell_end_today'] : $this->replacements['cal_cell_end'];
                } elseif ($this->show_other_days === TRUE) {
                    $out .= $this->replacements['cal_cell_start_other'];

                    if ($day <= 0) {
                        // Day of previous month
                        $prev_month      = $this->adjust_date($month - 1, $year);
                        $prev_month_days = $this->get_total_days($prev_month['month'], $prev_month['year']);
                        $out .= str_replace('{day}', $prev_month_days + $day, $this->replacements['cal_cell_other']);
                    } else {
                        // Day of next month
                        $out .= str_replace('{day}', $day - $total_days, $this->replacements['cal_cell_other']);
                    }

                    $out .= $this->replacements['cal_cell_end_other'];
                } else {
                    // Blank cells
                    $out .= $this->replacements['cal_cell_start'] . $this->replacements['cal_cell_blank'] . $this->replacements['cal_cell_end'];
                }

                $day++;
            }

            $out .= "\n" . $this->replacements['cal_row_end'] . "\n";
        }

        return $out .= "\n" . $this->replacements['table_close'];
    }
}
```

You can see my code diverges from native at line 108 with this snippet:

```
... if ($day < date('d')) {
    $out .= '&nbsp;';
} ...
```

As far as pagination, future months, and past months you will need to modify the snippet as you see fit.

Answer (score 1):

The answer below from William Knauss works out of the box (kudos to you William).
I actually went a little further with it and adapted William's solution to my needs.
Basically I wanted the days in the past to be disabled. As in, I wanted to put a class i the the td element for days in the past and a different class for the elements in the future (including today).
So, the code starting on line 106 looks as follows:

```
if ($day < date('d')) {
    $out .= ($is_current_month === TRUE && $day == $cur_day) ? $this->replacements['cal_cell_start_today'] : $this->replacements['cal_cell_start_past'];
}else{
    $out .= ($is_current_month === TRUE && $day == $cur_day) ? $this->replacements['cal_cell_start_today'] : $this->replacements['cal_cell_start'];
}

if (isset($data[$day])) { // this part was restored to the way it is in the native class.
     // Cells with content...
```

Notice the '**cal_cell_start_past**'. This is a new array property in the default_template array in the native class. Starting in line 473.
Now it looks like this:

```
'cal_row_start'             => '<tr>',
'cal_cell_start_past'       => '<td class="pastDay">',
'cal_cell_start'            => '<td class="day">',
'cal_cell_start_today'      => '<td class="day">',
```

Hope this helps someone else.